# How to change dataframe in R (extract first row for all ID by date)

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change my dataframe like this. How can I do it in R? Do I need double `For` loops to achieve this? (no matter how many travels he did in one day just extract the first history)

```
ID  DATE        Origin 
1   01/01/2012  A
1   01/01/2012  B
1   01/01/2012  C
1   01/02/2012  A
1   01/02/2012  B
1   01/02/2012  C
1   01/03/2012  A
1   01/03/2012  B
1   01/08/2012  A
2   01/01/2012  D
2   01/01/2012  C
2   01/01/2012  B
2   01/04/2012  D
2   01/04/2012  C
2   01/06/2012  D
3   01/03/2012  F
3   01/03/2012  G
3   01/09/2012  F
3   01/09/2012  G


 ID DATE        Origin
    1   01/01/2012  A
    1   01/02/2012  A
    1   01/03/2012  A
    1   01/08/2012  A
    2   01/01/2012  D
    2   01/04/2012  D
    2   01/06/2012  D
    3   01/03/2012  F
    3   01/09/2012  F
```

(I only want to remain the record like this one ↑) 
(**daily first trip** record for each passenger)

Comment: For future reference, please don't poste tables as pictures, as we can't copy and paste that for easy testing.

Comment: I'd recommed to explain further what do you need. Is it "sort by Origin" (and the second table is not complete)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First_Daily = aggregate(ORIGIN ~ ID + DATE, data=df, FUN='[', i=1)
```

this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

No loops needed. This is the simplest way to do it

```
df <- df[which(df$origin=="A"|df$origin=="D"|df$origin=="F"),]
```

You can also do it using `dplyr`.

Comment: I think he just wants the first row for each date. See title.

Comment: Yeah. Didn't notice that. Never looked at data in pictures before lol. Have to keep switching between tabs

Comment: Yeah, can't blame you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this?

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(ID, DATE) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the result achieved through this code is not really what I want. I want to get the first row for each date but also for each passenger (ID). for example, ID 1 --> Date 01/01/2012 ID 1 --> 01/02/2012 ... -->  and ID 2 --> 01/01/2012 ID 2 --> 02/01/2012 -->... (Just like I only need the daily first record for each passenger)

Comment: Sorry, your question really wasn't clear on that. I've made an edit.